# Porque sou proibido de perguntar se eu não faço mau uso do site?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, contas-usuário

Fui "proibido" de postar perguntas mas ninguém explica o pq.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes de como foi informado da proibição.

Comment: A proibição veio da versão em Inglês:


`You have reached your question limit`
`Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.`

Mas desde então eu não consigo mais postar perguntas na versão em português.

Comment: E você já leu a central de ajuda? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans Não conseguiu identificar um padrão para o bloqueio? Me parece que você tem várias perguntas sem votos. Destaco: **"Comece corrigindo suas publicações existentes"**.

Comment: Entendo que minhas publicações têm poucos votos e/ou respostas, mas acho que esse "algoritmo" está pensado de forma péssima.
Ora, minhas questões podem ter poucas respostas porque são questões específicas que poucas pessoas saberiam responder.

Comment: Ou que só servem para você que não é o objetivo deste site. Aqui é um repositório de perguntas úteis para as pessoas e não um fórum para resolver os problemas específicos de uma pessoa. Por isto aqui é melhor que os outros lugares para o todo. Claro que ele é pior para o individuo. Eu gosto dele porque prefiro salvar as pessoas do trem matando o cara preso no trilho do que descarrilhar o trem matando seus passageiros para salvar o cara no trilho.

Comment: Antes que essa conversa descarrilhe ainda mais, você **não foi bloqueado** pela qualidade dos seus posts. Longe disso. Você poderia postar um screenshot da tela de bloqueio para podermos dar uma olhada?

Comment: Aparentemente, você foi pego em um dos filtros contra spam. O seu browser está com Javascript habilitado? é nosso principal palpite por enquanto

Comment: Sim, meu browser está com JS habilitado.

Comment: @Neimeg Você instalou alguma extensão da semana passada pra cá? Algum ad blocker, lgum filtro de navegação, ou passou a usar um proxy?

Comment: Tenho o AdBlocker Plus instalado, mas já está instalado há mais de 1 mês.

Comment: Você pode postar em algum lugar o conteúdo do que ia perguntar?

Comment: Eu ia perguntar em inglês mas fui barrado, agora estou tentando postar em portugês mas, apesar de eu fazer o teste do captcha, o modal do mesmo não desaparece e a pergunta continuar sem ser postada. :/

Comment: @Neimeg e qual a razão de você postar em inglês? O erro aconteceu tentando postar aqui ou no SO original em inglês? Lá você também está com muitas perguntas sem votos.

Comment: @bigown eu tentei postar na versão em Inglês, só vim tirar a dúvida aqui porque a comunicação flui mellhor.

Comment: Se o problema acontece lá e não aqui, você tem que reclamar lá e não aqui.

Comment: @Neimeg Agora tá tudo confuso... Nossos logs apontam que você teve erros na hora de perguntar no SOpt ontem, mas você *também* tem um bloqueio ativo no SOen. O erro que você descreveu aqui foi em qual dos dois sites?

Comment: @Gabe, desculpe pela confusão, explico:
Eu tentei perguntar no SOen e percebi que eu havia sido "barrado", então tentei perguntar a mesma coisa no SOpt mas em português, mas não consegui postar minha pergunta porque captcha não desaparecia depois de eu marcar a opção "Não sou um robô".

Eu preferi tirar minha dúvida sobre a minha proibição aqui no SOpt pq a comunicação é mais fácil e, acredito, as regras sejam as mesmas.

Então temos aí 2 problemas relatados: SOen me barrou por eu ter muitas pergunas sem resposta e SOpt estava com erro na validação do captcha ou algo assim.

Comment: Há poucos instantes eu consegui postar uma pergunta e, aparentemente, tudo voltou ao normal no SOpt. No SOen ainda estou barrado, mesmo depois de ter apagado minhas perguntas sem resposta e aceitado algumas respotas de outros usuários.

Comment: @Neimeg Beleza. Vou escrever a resposta então, considerando tudo.

Comment: Neimeg, se já esta barrado no SOen, deletar perguntas só piora sua situação...

Answer (score 6):

Você não está impedido de fazer perguntas (ou responder) no SOpt. Você teve problemas com o filtro anti-spam aqui ontem, como você [relatou sobre o captcha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4243/porque-sou-proibido-de-perguntar-se-eu-n%C3%A3o-fa%C3%A7o-mau-uso-do-site?noredirect=1#comment12178_4243). Isso pode ter sido causado pelo seu AdBlock, ou problemas de rede, ou minha teoria favorita: Gremlins. Não tem como saber exatamente o que aconteceu, mas o problema parece resolvido.

Quanto ao SOen, lá você realmente está impedido de perguntar [até melhorar a qualidade do seus posts existentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Você ja tentou [apagar perguntas antigas e aceitar respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4243/porque-sou-proibido-de-perguntar-se-eu-n%C3%A3o-fa%C3%A7o-mau-uso-do-site?noredirect=1#comment12194_4243), mas a única maneira de reverter a o ban é editando as perguntas existentes e melhorando sua qualidade. Não existe outra.

As regras para esses bloqueios são as mesmas em todos os sites, mas eles funcionam independentemente. Elas levam em consideração apenas posts naquele site, então você pode estar bloqueado no SOen mas não aqui ou vice-versa. Isso vale para todos os sites da rede.

Reveja suas perguntas no SOen, leia os comentários, veja o que pode ser melhorado, e você poderá voltar a perguntar lá.

Boa sorte!